# add related articles inside content of an instant articles fb

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I need to add some related posts in the content of an instant articles. 
I use this WordPress plugin:

https://github.com/Automattic/facebook-instant-articles-wp

My posts have:

```
<ul class="related-article">
  <li>
     <a href="http://example.com/"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I add this in my transformer rules

```
{
      "class": "RelatedArticlesRule",
      "selector": ".related-article"

},
{
      "class": "RelatedItemRule",
      "selector": ".related-article li",
      "properties": {
        "related.url": {
          "type": "string",
          "selector": "a",
          "attribute": "href"
        }
      }
}
```

But in trasformer markup the related ul not exists.
I need something like that:

```
<ul class="op-related-article">
  <li>
     <a href="http://example.com/"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like related articles items are checked only inside `RelatedArticlesRule` so your selector is wrong.

This should work:

```
{
  "class": "RelatedArticlesRule",
  "selector": "ul.related-article",
  "properties" : {
    "related.title" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "selector" : "ul.related-article",
        "attribute": "title"
     }
  }
},
{
  "class": "RelatedItemRule",
  "selector": "li",
  "properties": {
    "related.url": {
      "type": "string",
      "selector": "a",
      "attribute": "href"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do You have any warnings from transformer?

Comment: Is not exists some markup standard for related articles?

Comment: As You want to have then in article content - not footer then probably title is needed for related articles section. Add title property to your `ul` element. `<ul class="related-article" title="My title">`.

Comment: Doc's and examples are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/related-articles And check if your rules are properly loaded by transformer - there must be some errors if it's not recognized.